# gettimeofday() fails with ERRNO 75

Tags: android, c, linux

The following code in a program executed in an Android 12 phone:

```c
struct timeval tv;
int ret = gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
if (ret < 0)
    printf("gettimeofday failed with %s\n", strerror(errno));
printf("%lu.%ld\n", tv.tv_sec, tv.tv_usec);
```

returns

```
gettimeofday failed with Value too large for defined data type
1078605538.1
```

Furthermore, the seconds and useconds are always constant even if called inside a loop.
Exact same results with using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tv);`

There must be something going wrong since `gettimeofday()` isn't supposed to return errno 75 according to the manpages.

strace output:

```
read(3, " \0\0\0\1\0\0\0\273\0\0\0\230\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\20\0\254\0\254\0\223\261zG\377F"..., 65536) = 199
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {tv_sec=3416400658881740019, tv_nsec=4632575514938983213}) = 0
dup(2)                                  = 4
fcntl64(4, F_GETFL)                     = 0x20002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
statx(4, "", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT|AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT|AT_EMPTY_PATH, STATX_BASIC_STATS, {stx_mask=STATX_BASIC_STATS, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, stx_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(4, "gettimeofday: Value too large fo"..., 52gettimeofday: Value too large for defined data type
) = 52
close(4)
[ and same repeats, we are in a loop ]
```

Comment: `1078605538` is sometime back in 2004, but _probably_ it's just stack garbage.  If you add `memset(&tv, 0, sizeof tv)` immediately before the `gettimeofday` call, does that make it start printing `0.0` instead?

Comment: I would also double-check that the system clock is actually set correctly; this could be some sort of sanity check along the lines of "if the clock is set to a date before Android 12 was released, something must be wrong".

Comment: It's possible something called inside `gettimeofday` is returning -1, but being cast as an unsigned integer which could make it seem very large. It's that something which is setting `errno`. Remember, `errno` is a global.

Comment: @zwol yes, prints 0.0 after adding `memset()`.  The system clock is set, running `date` gives the correct time and another application using python's `datetime.now()` (which, to my understanding, uses gettimeofday() or something similar) gets the time correctly.

Comment: OK, the next thing I would try is running the program under `strace`.  (This will produce several hundred lines of output, we need to see the _last_ 30 lines or so.)

Comment: @zwol had to compile strace for android, added what I believed to be the relevant strace output to the post. Did not see EOVERFLOW or 75 anywhere in strace output

Comment: That is some puzzling `strace` output: `clock_gettime` returns `0` (which I assume is what the `gettimeofday` libc wrapper calls), but then you check `errno` and it's not `0`... something is broken. Also, is the fd for `stdout` somehow `4`? Or are you writing somewhere else? That's weird. Are you sure that's exactly the code you are running? E.G. if you put just those few lines in an `int main(void)` and run it do you get the same result?

Comment: What is the device and OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was some kind of an Android related issue. After switching from cross compiling with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc to using ndk-build, this issue was resolved.

Not exactly sure of root cause, but something with the Makefile was off.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a regression in recent Android kernels. Note that this only affects 32-bit ARM code running on a 64-bit kernel. Probably your NDK targets AArch64.